# Spring Security - Oauth2 Pass Request Paramerter to the AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring-security

I have created a custom authentication provider to which I need to pass a parameter from the request.

The enpoint is

> /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=xxx&password=xxx&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&country=my

From the above request I need to capture the `country` parameter and pass it on to the custom authentication provider, which will then authenticate the user based on his username, password and country.

The above request passes through the `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` filter, but there is no way I can set the country value from the request onto the authentication object.

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="never"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="fullyAuthenticated" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />     
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
```

Please let me know if I can have this implemented by extending any of the security features.

I am using `Spring 4.1` and `Spring Security 4.0.3RELEASE`

Thanks,
Anwar

Answer (score 0):

You need to Create a `UsernamePasswordCountryAuthenticationToken`.

```
public class UsernamePasswordCountryAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {

    private String country;

    public UsernamePasswordCountryAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, String country, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)    {
        super(principal, credentials, country, authorities);
    }

    public UsernamePasswordCountryAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, String country)    {
        super(principal, credentials, country);
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
}
```

And override `ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter`

```
public class CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter extends AbstractTokenGranter {

    private static final String GRANT_TYPE = "password";

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
        AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices, ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        super(tokenServices, clientDetailsService, GRANT_TYPE);
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }


    protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication(AuthorizationRequest clientToken) {
        Map<String, String> parameters = clientToken.getAuthorizationParameters();
        String username = parameters.get("username");
        String password = parameters.get("password");
        String country = parameters.get("country");

        Authentication userAuth = new UsernamePasswordCountryAuthenticationToken(username, password, country);
        try {
             userAuth = authenticationManager.authenticate(userAuth);
        } catch (AccountStatusException ase) {
            //covers expired, locked, disabled cases (mentioned in section 5.2, draft 31)
            throw new InvalidGrantException(ase.getMessage());
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            // If the username/password are wrong the spec says we should send 400/bad grant
            throw new InvalidGrantException(e.getMessage());
        }

        if (userAuth == null || !userAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
            throw new InvalidGrantException("Could not authenticate user: " + username);
        }

        return new OAuth2Authentication(clientToken, userAuth);
    }
}
```

And Finally in your Spring Security OAuth configuration file

```
<bean id="customResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter" class="CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="tokenServices"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="clientDetailsService"/>
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server ...>
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="customResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter" />
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

Now if you have correctly Configured your `AuthenticationManager` to have your custom `AuthenticationProvider`, you will be receiving an instance of `UsernamePasswordCountryAuthenticationToken` to `AuthenticationProvider.authenticate method(Authentication auth)` where you can cast `auth` to `UsernamePasswordCountryAuthenticationToken` and make use.